# Django how to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN equivalent (show left data even when no right pair exists)?

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm

I have two tables:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    regularprice = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

class Override(models.Model):
    productcode = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    specialprice = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)


Data Example
============
Product
Code    RegularPrice
C101        1.25
C102        2.50
C103        3.00

Override
ProductCode SpecialPrice
C102        1.50
```

I want to do equivalent of a left outer join.  The result set I want to achieve would be:

```
Code    RegularPrice     SpecialPrice
C101        1.25        NULL
C102        2.50          1.50
C103        3.00         NULL
```

How would I do this?

---

EDIT: I am trying to achieve a base price list, with optional override values.  The base prices are generated, with any override values appended alongside (or NULL if none present).

Very sorry but I did leave out an important element of this question thinking it would make it simpler.  Each Override has a column called Customer.  The Override class has UNIQUE TOGETHER on "customerid" and "code" (so one override per code, per customer).

I wish to generate a PriceList of all Products + if any Overrides are present for the particular Customer they will be shown alongside the corresponding Product line.

The ORM query looks like this:
pricelist = Product.objects.select_related().filter(Override__customerid=1)

But this only does a regular join (omitting any Product that isnt paired with an Override), I want a LEFT OUTER JOIN displaying everything in the Product table, with any Overrides joined (if present, or NULL)

Many thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

In what context? If all you're looking to do is print this out, you can just use:

```
products = Product.objects.all()
```

or whatever `Product` query you want, then loop through in a template like:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {{product.code}}
    {{product.regularprice}}
    {{product.override.specialprice|default:"NULL"}}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want a more efficient database query, you can use `select_related` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)):

```
products = Product.objects.select_related('override')
```

but this will **only** work if you're using a `OneToOneField` for `productcode`, **not** a `ForeignKey`:

```
class Override(models.Model):
    productcode = models.OneToOneField(Product)
```

Comment: select_related cannot follow backwards relationships.  You kinda note that...but what you're showing just won't work

Comment: @John - according to the docs, `select_related` *can* follow backwards relationships, but *only* for `OneToOneField`s, as I note in my answer (I'll emphasize it a bit more, if that helps). It seems like using a `OneToOneField` might be a perfectly reasonable option in the OP's case.

Comment: OneToOneFields in general should be avoided.  They represent an unnecessary join for data you should most likely just have on the main model.  The only real good use for them is if you have some subset of data that is really expensive to get out of the database and is rarely used.  With that said, my reading of the models imply's he has a one to many and may not realize it

Comment: Many thanks for answering, I can see I have left out important info and have revised my question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've set up the relationship between Product and Override is one to many.  Which means that for every Product you'll have (potentially) many Overrides.

So now you'll want to think about what you want to generate and that will determine how you want to query this.

If you want a list of Overrides then simply query Override.objects.all().select_related()

Then you can generate a list of Overrides and their associated Product's data by following the foreignkeys:

```
o = Override.objects.all()[0]
o.product.regularprice
```

If you want a list of products each with their own list of overrides then you should look at the itertools grouby function (or if you're in a template use the django `regroup` tag)

Comment: Many thanks for answering but I left out important info, I have revised my question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not currently possible with the Django's ORM and you have to use a `raw` query.